# AngularJS - Cookies & Cookiestore

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies

I'm making a game and I want to use cookies to save the player's progress. I read the basics on how to use cookies and cookiestore, but I'm having trouble to get started using it.

After some tests I noticed that the game keeps the data if the user refreshes the page, but if he closes the browser, the data is gone. Any methods to save data even if the user closes the browser?

Another thing is that I need to check if the player already has saved cookies or if it's the first time he is playing, so I can retrieve the cookies or set the initial values for the variables.

I don't have any code with the cookies to show yet, but what I'm trying to do, regarding saving, is the same as happens on this game: http://orteil.dashnet.org/cookieclicker/

Thank you in advance.

Comment: As mentioned in the docs, `ngCookies` deals with session-cookies (i.e. the kind that dies when the browser is closed). For a more persistent storage option, you should use HTML5 localStorage.

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice that. Well, I guess I'll take a look at what you said. Thank you very much.